# MongoDb query - aggregation, group, filter, max

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to figure out specific mongoDb query, so far unsuccessfully.

Documents in my collections looks someting like this (contain more attributes, which are irrelevant for this query):

```
[{
    "_id": ObjectId("596e01b6f4f7cf137cb3d096"),
    "code": "A",
    "name": "name1",
    "sys": {
        "cts": ISODate("2017-07-18T12:40:22.772Z"),
    }
}, 
{
    "_id": ObjectId("596e01b6f4f7cf137cb3d097"),
    "code": "A",
    "name": "name2",
    "sys": {
        "cts": ISODate("2017-07-19T12:40:22.772Z"),
    }
}, 
{
    "_id": ObjectId("596e01b6f4f7cf137cb3d098"),
    "code": "B",
    "name": "name3",
    "sys": {
        "cts": ISODate("2017-07-16T12:40:22.772Z"),
    }
}, 
{
    "_id": ObjectId("596e01b6f4f7cf137cb3d099"),
    "code": "B",
    "name": "name3",
    "sys": {
        "cts": ISODate("2017-07-10T12:40:22.772Z"),
    }
}]
```

What I need is to get current versions of documents, filtered by code or name, or both. Current version means that from two(or more) documents with same code, I want pick the one which has latest sys.cts date value.

So, result of this query executed with filter name="name3" would be the 3rd document from previous list. Result of query without any filter would be 2nd and 3rd document.

I have an idea how to construct this query with changed data model but I was hoping someone could lead me right way without doing so.
Thank you

Comment: You can try `db.collectionname.aggregate([
  {
    "$match":{...}
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "sys.cts": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$name",
      "latest": {
        "$first": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  }
]);`

Comment: @Veeram thank you. After adding $replaceRoot at the end its working as I wanted.